# Extension Method For IQueryable not working

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I have written an extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> ConditionalDefaultEmpty<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition)
{
    return condition ? source.DefaultIfEmpty() : source ;
}
```

And then I called the method, something like this :

```
var q = from sr in myDb.tblStudentsRegInfos
        from de in myDb.tblDisciplinesEvents.Where(e => sr.Serial == e.tblStudentsRegInfoRef 
                                                     && e.tblStudentsRegInfoRef == studentRegId 
                                                     && (!forStudent || e.PublishOnInternet)
                                                     && (!formDate.HasValue || e.RegDate >= formDate) 
                                                     && (!toDate.HasValue || e.RegDate <= toDate))
                    .ConditionalDefaultEmpty(noPrintAll)
        join dt in myDb.tblDisciplinesTitles on de.tblDisciplinesTitlesRef equals dt.Serial
        where sr.Serial == studentRegId
        group sr by new
                {
...
                }
                into std
                select new
                {....
                };
```

But I get this error :

> Member access [column name] is not legal ....

How can I fix this issue ?

**Update : I had understand that EF Cannot Compile to IQueryable...**

Comment: Does the query work when you don't use your method?

Comment: yes it's work very nice.

Comment: Can you execute the second from (the part with your method) as separate query?

Comment: unfortunately no , or I don't think so

Comment: I mean, does it crash or you cannot test it?

Comment: queries are not sepratable

Comment: Yes they are, just extract it and run ToList on it. The thing is, there should be no problem with your ConditionalDefaultEmpty method. And the error doesn't fit the idea that the method is the core problem.. So I'm thinking the real problem is somewhere else in the query. Maybe some part you are not showing. Best way to debug LINQ is to cut it into pieces and test every piece separately.

Comment: I would suspect that theres a column in your query, thats not at Database level, which would then mean using an IQueryable is not possible. As suggested, diasect your code into smaller queries

Comment: no all cols are in db level

Answer (score -1):

You just can't add your custom extension method and hope that Entity framework will be able to translate it into SQL, though that would be pretty cool, atleast for cases like these.

That said, you can turn `IQueryable` into `IEnumerable`:

```
.AsEnumerable()
.ConditionalDefaultEmpty(noPrintAll)
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, because this is precisely the reason. Maybe it's because `AsEnumerable()` in a subquery won't help, because EF won't be able to translate only the first part of the query into SQL and do the rest in memory.